# Push file to Github,but the size of file has limit

Tags: github, filesize

I want to push file to Github,but the size of file can't over 100M,but I have a single file is 145M,how can I push it to Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Large File Storage and track your file:

https://git-lfs.github.com/

Once you have done this you should be able to push it to GitHub